# Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, custom-function

[image: The Error Message]

I have a .tsv file from a tool and I have to import it the Google Sheet (nearly) real-time for reports. This is my code for importing:

```
function importBigTSV(url) {return Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(),'\t');}
```

It worked till some days ago when Error messages keep saying "Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0)."

Could anyone help? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Custom functions have a time limit of 30s. Consider creating a menu or button to execute script.

Comment: [oups, overlapped with TheMaster] Most likely you started hitting a [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) - check if your custom functions return under 30 sec (+UrlFetchApp.fetch timeouts in 30s) via "View -> Executions" menu item. Once you do, if everything seems ok or if you don't know how to debug - update the question and one of us surely will try to help (also, you can ping me to check up on the question)

Comment: To be honest, I am a newbie and I found it very difficult to turn a custom function into a script for scheduling. Could anyone please help me on this? I hope that my request is not too demanding :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Issue:

As @TheMaster said, custom functions have a hard limit of [30 seconds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values), which your function is most probably reaching. Regular Apps Script executions have a much more generous time limit (6 or 30 minutes, depending on your account), so you should modify your function accordingly.

#### Differences between functions:

In order to transform your function, you have to take into account these basic differences:

- You cannot pass parameters to a function called by a Menu or a button. Because of this, you have to find another way to specify the URL to fetch.
- Values returned by a regular function don't get automatically written to the sheet. You have to use a writing method (like `setValues`, or `appendRow`) to do that.
- A non-custom function is not called in any particular cell, so you have to specify where do you want to write the values to.

Since, from what I understand, you are always fetching the same URL, you can specify that URL just by hardcoding it into your function.

#### Solution:

The function below, for example, will write the parsed output to the range that is currently selected (at the moment of triggering the function). You could as well provide a default range to write the output to, using [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)):

```js
function importBigTSV() {
  var url = "{url-to-fetch}";
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  try {
    var output = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(),'\t');
    var outputRange = range.offset(0, 0, output.length, output[0].length);
    outputRange.setValues(output);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

If the URL can change, I'd suggest you to have a list of URLs to fetch, and, before triggering the function, select the desired URL, and use `getActiveRange` in order to get this URL.

#### Attaching function to Menu:

In any case, once you have written your function, you have to attach this function somehow, so that it can be trigged from the sheet itself. You can either create a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms), or insert and image or drawing, and [attach the script to it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets). The referenced links provide clear and concise steps to achieve this.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions > Return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values)
- [Custom Menus in G Suite](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)

Comment: I am not sure I understand bullet point 3, does the previous bullet point not cover it?

Comment: @Jonathon They're related, but I added both points in order to clarify the situation.

Comment: Hi, I am here. The code has worked perfectly for the last several months and I love it!

But the problem came last week since it is the first time my data make the code run for more than 6 mins, which is the limit for a script. What could I do now? I am thinking of separating the task into smaller tasks but it seems not possible for me. 

Could you please help?

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcLong Sorry for the late response, I just noticed your comment. If you're still having this issue, I'd suggest you to post a new question, including the code you are working on and explaining why splitting into smaller tasks doesn't seem to be possible. Cheers!